# Single word for 'less expensive'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, comparatives

Is there a good single word for 'less expensive'?

I often see people using 'cheap' to describe it, but I feel it does not express the intention. For example, I prefer to say 'Flight tickets are less expensive.' instead of 'Flight tickets are cheap'.

Comment: Actually, "cheaper" is probably the best equivalent to "less expensive".

Comment: The edit completely changes OP

Comment: @MarkBeadles The edit also makes the question less internally consistent interchanging 'cheaper' and 'cheap'.

Comment: It depends on the context and intention. So, **economical**, **reasonable** and even **closeout** could be appropriate alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

low-cost 
: obtainable at a low cost
— U.S. News & World Report
low-cost housing
(From Merriam-Webster's Dictionary)

Comment: “Low cost” counts as 2 words; the OP wants only 1.

Comment: There are two roots but there is one word.

Answer (score 1):

*affordable* might work:

> able to be afforded : having a cost that is not too high
>   // products sold at affordable prices
>   // an affordable purchase

<sub>(source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affordable))</sub>

Generally speaking: cheap < affordable < expensive. Whether this will work in your specific case is hard to tell without more context.

Comment: But something can be less expensive but still not affordable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few words that mean 'low-cost' that I can think of:

***Inexpensive***

*Not costing a great deal; cheap.*

***Cheap***

*Low in price, especially in relation to similar items or services.*

and finally,

***Economical***

*Giving good value or return in relation to the money, time, or effort expended.*

Obviously *affordable*, but it's already been mentioned.

**All definitions taken from the Oxford English Dictionary.**

Comment: Cheap could mean low quality and negative impression. I don't know if it can be an alternative to "less expensive"...

Comment: @wonhee No, it's just some people make that connection.  'Cheap' was never intended to mean this.

Comment: Yeah but there are so many people outside, including me, make a connection "cheap" with "low quality". I guess that's why it's better using other alternatives (inexpensive, cost-effective, or even affordable although it's not quite fit in this situation ) instead of "cheap". If you have a company and make a new product/service, you will never want them to call "cheap" to avoid the negative impression that customer might get from the word?

https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/3455-cheap-prices-customers.html